# Android webview on document ready callback

Tags: android, webview

When using WebView , is there a way to detect whether the document DOM tree has been loaded finish? I know that the WebViewClient provides a 'onPageFinish' callback,but it's called after all the web resources has been loaded finish.

If the web page is running a slow request (may be a bad request,and its http status is "waiting for responses"), then the "onPageFinish" won't be called until the request finish.  I just want to catch the event when the web page's DOM tree loaded finish.

Any one help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Use onPageCommitVisible replace onPageFinished.

```
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        prDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        prDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        prDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
        if(prDialog != null) prDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has event that use to detect completed building the DOM tree called `DOMContentLoaded`.

[JavaScript Page Load Events](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-page-load-events)

You can inject Javascript with `addJavascriptInterface()` and let it call the function in Native side that defined with `JavaScriptInterface` annotation, then execute the `DOMContentLoaded` with `evaluateJavascript` like

```kotlin
webView.apply {
    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    // Inject Javascript
    addJavascriptInterface(
        DomContentLoadedInterface({ /* Do something */ }),
        DomContentLoadedInterface.KEY
    )

    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url)
            // Execute Javascript
            evaluateJavascript(DomContentLoadedInterface.SCRIPT)
        }
    }

    loadUrl(URL)
}
```

where `DomContentLoadedInterface` is

```kotlin
class DomContentLoadedInterface(private val action: () -> Unit) {

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun execute() {
        action()
    }

    companion object {
        internal const val KEY = "DomContentLoaded"
        internal const val SCRIPT = "javascript:document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){DomContentLoaded.execute()})"
    }
}
```

Note: `evaluateJavascript` will work in `onLoadResource` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58932747/9896693) and after `onPageFinished`

Answer (score -1):

Here my example.For page

boolean isPageLoaded;
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          isPageLoaded=true;
            return isPageLoaded;
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

       if(!isPageLoaded){}

        }
    });
```

> My examples for url loading finished.

if(!isPageLoaded){}

> if url has ok process finished.

Comment: May be my question is not clear. I know the 'onPageFinished' callback,but this callback is called after all the resources request finished.If one of the requests not return, then the 'onPageFinished' won't be called.